Why do transactions duplicate the accounts used?
I'm looking at the structure of a Solana transaction and it seems a few bytes are wasted by duplicating the list of accounts used.
From my understanding, first the public key of all transactions are included in the "accountKeys" field of the message.
Then the "accounts" section which contains "AccountMeta" also has a "pubkey" sub-field which contains the public key of the account being referenced. However, the he same data is already included in the "accountKeys" field.
I believe quite a few bytes can be saved by removing the "accountKeys" section completely or having each the "pubkey" field only reference the index of the account in the "accountKeys" field.
Let me know if and where I've made any mistakes. Thank you!

Not quite! This is the format of a non-serialized transaction. When a transaction gets serialized, it has each account key once in an array of of addresses and all AccountMetas inside instructions don't use the address to refer to accounts anymore but instead a 1-byte index referring to said array. Check out the two linked sections for more info.

Thanks!
If possible, I'd love if you could point me to where that's documented.

Click on the two links of my answer, those two spots have more info on that
